# Use a JSON file as Docker Secret for Dockerfile

Tags: json, mongodb, docker

Let's say I have a JSON file I'm using for seeding a MongoDB database:

```
[
  {
    "name": "New User",
    "email": "newuser@test.com"
    "password": "HelloWorld_1337"
  }
]
```

And I'm using this JSON file on my Dockerfile for a container called `mongo-seed`:

```
FROM mongo

COPY first_user.json /first_user.json
# This script seeds the MongoDB
COPY seed_db.sh /seed_db.sh

CMD ["bash", "/seed_data.sh"]
```

However, since I don't want end users to see the contents of my JSON file, is there a way I can convert it to a Docker Secret? What I've read in the official documentation, it only works with individual variables, and I even tried to create the secret using the file itself:

`docker secret create first_user ./path/to/first_user.json`

But when I try to run my project using my `docker-compose.yml` file, I get the following error:

`failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref [key]::[value]: "/run/secrets/first_user": not found`

Comment: I hope this is just an example. You should **never** store passwords in a database! And it would be even worse if you store them as clear text. Store password hash-values instead.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, this is just an example